# File size discrepancy between du command and Python function

Tags: python, bash, recursion, size, du

I have a script I run nightly to get the ammt of stuff stored in a specific directory on my server. This is the function I am using for that core part:

```
def get_size(start_path = '.'):
    total_size = 0
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(start_path):
        for f in filenames:
            try:
                fp = os.path.join(dirpath, f)
                total_size += os.path.getsize(fp)
                print str(total_size)+" bytes / "+str(size(total_size))+" counted"+" <------------ current position: "+start_path+" : "+f
                for location in locations_dict:
                    if locations_dict[location][1] != "":
                        print str(location)+": "+str(size(locations_dict[location][1]))
            except OSError, e:
                print e
    return total_size
```

For some reason, I am getting a different value when I manually run

```
$ du -hc [path to dir]
```

With the Python I get 20551043874445 bytes (converts to 20.5 TB). With `du` I get 
28 TB (I am re-running now without `-h` to get the value in bytes).

Clearly that Python function is missing something, but I'm not sure what or how. Any ideas?

Comment: `du` measures the amount used on disk (so, rounded up to the filesystem block size), whereas `os.path.getsize()` returns the size in bytes of the file contents. But that could only account for this much of a difference if your directory contains lots and lots of small files.

Comment: There are at least 60,000 to 100,000 small files – is that enough to account for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`du` shows the size in 512-byte blocks. If the file size isn't a multiple of 512, `du` rounds up. To get the equivalent value in Python, instead of using `os.path.getsize()`, use `os.stat()` and use the `st_blocks` attribute of the result.

```
total_size += os.stat(fp).st_blocks * 512;
```

Comment: So in some sense the Python result is more accurate, but from the perspective of showing "how much space is being used" is it more accurate to round up and behave like du?

Comment: If you want to know how close you are to filling the disk, you want to know about disk blocks. If you want to know how long it will take to transfer the files over the network, you want to know about the size in bytes.

Comment: What if the `du` result is _smaller_ than the python result?

Comment: @Anonymous Not sure what would cause that. AFAIK, `du` uses the same `st_blocks` attribute that I use above.